# Setar valor de uma ROW null ou empty em um gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

Trago um Datatable do banco de dados e preencho em um ***gridview***, preciso deixar algumas `ROWS` em branco ou sem nada, porem os campos são numericos e não aceitam *string* ou outro tipo.

```
DataTable dt = ClassesControle.CNProduto.listaProdutos(null, usuario);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(row["PRECO"]) == 0.0)
                    row["PRECO"] = "";
             }
```

ERRO: O Tipo esperado é SINGLE (FLOAT).

Comment: Em vez de colocar `row["PRECO"] = "";` experimenta `row["PRECO"] = null;`

Comment: ja tentei, não aceita tambem!

Answer (score 4):

Resolve se alterar apenas o valor exibido no GridView? Você poderia fazer algo no evento `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)    
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "0.00") //selecione o index correto do campo no gridView
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solução 1**

Você pode fazer com que na hora de criar o DataTable os campos que podem ficar vazios sejam do tipo `Nullable` como o caso de `double?` para permitir o null

Edit: **Solução 2**

Você fazer essa alteração no `RowDataBound` de sua `GridView`

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Text = e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Text == 0.00 ? string.Empty : e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Text;
    }
}
```

Essa é outra maneira

Comment: Ele aceita um tipo para cada campo? Ou um tipo para cada COLUNA?

Comment: Cada coluna, mas recomendo usar somente nas colunas que REALMENTE ficarão vazias ou nulas

Answer (score 1):

O valor correspondente ao **NULL** da base de dados é: [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx).

Tenta assim:

```
DataTable dt = ClassesControle.CNProduto.listaProdutos(null, usuario);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(row["PRECO"]) == 0.0)
    {
        row["PRECO"] = DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```